# How do I update static objects separately?

Tags: java, static, 2d, render

I'm currently working on a small project in Java. I am doing a 2D Minecraft game and want to add tiles/blocks to the map.

I know how to add blocks and stuff that are static to make them all render with only one sprite, but if I want to add a block, let's say a sapling, I want to update it all the time, but that seems to be impossible when it is static without making every other sapling doing the exact same thing...

So I am wondering if there is a way to make the block update by itself but still only render it with one sprite?

Comment: Welcome to Stack OverFlow.Please show us what you have tried, show us your code and we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to identify each individual block, in this case the sapling, with a unique identifier so that it can be referenced individually. The way that Minecraft does it, I believe is based on the block location.  So you would reference that specific block in such a way;

```
 (Pseudo-code) 

 Block block = world.getBlock(x, y, z);
 updateSprite(block);
```

In your case probably just an x,y coordinate as your mapping in 2D. Have you looked at Terraria at all?